# How many bytes are transferred in an SSL handshake?

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to calculate how much bandwidth my app can use and I heard that the SLL handshake can use 2k. That sounds like a lot. Is it true?

***Roughly*** how many bytes are transferred in an SSL handshake?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a large number of factors, such as:

- the number of cipher suites supported by the client
- the number of CAs the client trusts
- the length of the server certificate chain
- the actual cipher suite negotiated
- whether or not an existing SSL session is resumed
- whether or not a client certificate is requested
- if a client certificate is requested, the number of CAs the server trusts
- whether or not a client certificate is supplied, which isn't the same thing
- the length of the client certificate chain, if any

And so on and so on. There is no single answer, and several of these factors have a major effect on the total byte count.

2k isn't a lot BTW.

Comment: > 2k isn't a lot BTW.

Not a particularly helpful opine.